# Angular2 - Cloning a variable to not modify source

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component which is displaying some data on a page from a subscription.

I am trying to `clone` that variable and make changes to it without impacting the original data being used to render the view of the page.

```
import { UtilsService } from '../shared';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-review',
    templateUrl: './review.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./review.component.css']
})
export class ReviewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() payload: any = null;

    // Object of strings that are used for the details
    langStr: any = {
        noDepartment: 'No Department Change',
        noSegment: 'No Segment Change',
        noMarket: 'No Budget Market Change',
        noIncentive: 'No Incentive Plan Change',
        noRole: 'No Role Change',
        noProductionDate: 'No Production Date Change',
        noLanguage: 'No Language Change',
        noShift: 'No Shift Change',
        noSupervisor: 'No Supervisor Change'
    };

    // Used to scan through the final payload and assign default values if missing
    optionalFields = ['budgetMarket',
        'hierarchy',
        'incentivePlan',
        'primaryLanguage',
        'secondaryLanguage',
        'role',
        'segment',
        'shiftID',
        'supervisor'];

    modifiedData: any;

    constructor(
        private utils: UtilsService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() { }

    submitChanges() {

        this.modifiedData = this.payload;

        // Loop over all of the keys in our formData object
        for (const key in this.modifiedData.formData) {

            // Find shift by property if the key exists within our defined array
            if (this.modifiedData.formData.hasOwnProperty(key) && this.utils.isInArray(this.optionalFields, key)) {

                // If our object data doesnt have a value, set it to -1
                if (!this.modifiedData.formData[key].length) {
                    this.modifiedData.formData[key] = '-1';
                }

            }

        }

        // Send to database 
        console.log(this.modifiedData)
    }

}
```

In this situation above, I am trying to set my subscribed data of `this.payload` to a new variable called `modifiedData`. I am then modifying some of the data in that assignment.

However, as soon as I call the function `submitChanges()`, my HTML view gets updates with the changes made to `modifiedData`, even though its not subscribed to that.

I assume it is something to do with `this.modifiedData = this.payload;` somehow updating the original data (`payload`).

Is there a way to do this where `payload` wouldn't be touched. I am essentially just cloning that and making a few changes before submitting it to my database call.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, since he's not asking on how to clone, but for an error in his code which is because of how objects are treated in terms of referencing. Both lead to the same answers though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not cloning the object. You are just assigning the reference to that object to another variable. They both point at the exact same object.

If you want to actually clone your object you have basically two options:

First, easy, a little bit hacky and to be used carefully since not everything will be covered:

```
this.modifiedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.payload));
```

will give you a new object basically cloned.

If you want to have a more robust cloning, you have to do it manually by traversing through your object and creating a new one from scratch (or use a library like lodash, which has methods for this).

---

Update just for completion: The other answers suggested `this.modifiedData Object.assign({}, this.payload)` and `this.modifiedData = {...this.payload};` which is fine for simple, not nested objects because both do a `shallow copy` not a `deep copy` of your object.

Since `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)` will ignore everything else than Objects, Arrays, Numbers and Strings and Booleans, the probably best option to take is still a manual clone (or using a library which does it like lodash).

Comment: I went with your `lodash` suggestion and used `this.modifiedData = _.cloneDeep(this.payload);` for my solution.

Comment: Would take this way, too but didn't wanted only to suggest to use a library :). Glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
    // Clone the object to retain a copy
    this.originalProduct = Object.assign({}, value);
```

Or in your case:

```
    this.modifiedData = Object.assign({}, this.payload);
```

This copies the values of all properties from `this.payload` into a *new* object.

The documentation for this is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign AND includes a discussion of the "deep cloning" issues.

Otherwise, this code:

```
 this.modifiedData = this.payload;
```

is assigning a reference. So any change to the original changes the "copy" as well.

Comment: this will have no effect on the mutation of the `formData`

Comment: aren't there some issues with deep cloning with that approach?

Comment: @lexith, it's not deepcloning, it's shallow clone

Comment: Thanks. yes. So it's not really advisable.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. If you are doing something simple, then it works. I have used it in several of my editing features to keep track of the "before" values and it worked fine.